# Provide hyperlink column doesn't open formview

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have made a Hyperlink column for that i am following below steps mention in link, But Grid column is showing as Hyperlink but on click link, doesn't open edit form. 
Steps i am following

1. Field has selector attribute.
2. It contains primary key of reference DAC.
3. I am not setting Linkcommend, If need then what it should be?

How may i redirect user to open edit form on link click?

https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(1))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=b58cf22a-054d-4cec-971a-8a7c3d24e338

Comment: is the hyperlink being shown but nothing is happening? Are you redirecting to a new page or to an Acumatica page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the redirection provided by the PXSelectorAttribute when setting the AllowEdit = true, ensure that the referenced DAC has the PXPrimaryGraphAttribute set, especially if it is a custom DAC. This will allow the framework to know which Graph and Screen to redirect to.

Example:

Selector:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<SOOrder.orderNbr>))]
```

DAC:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(SOOrderEntry))]
public class SOOrder : IBqlTable
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: I did same but still click on link nothing happen.

How to make a field segment field and make it as hyperlink?
Also in customization screen, i don't see AllowEdit option for selector, why?